# How to control the transaction in psql file

Tags: postgresql

In a testing.psql file have the following script.

```
do
$$  
 BEGIN
 UPDATE confi set val = 'YES' Where Name ='ISVALIDCUST';

                              --savepoint 1 here; 
perform testUpdateAdjust1(
        tname      => 'Test1',
        custnumber => 'custno1121',
        custid     => 61,
        regid      => 'F');  
                              --rollback to 1 here; 

                             --savepoint  2  here; 
perform testUpdateAdjust2(
        tname        => 'Test2',
        custnumber   => 'custno1122',
        custid       => 34,
        regid        => 'T'
        );   
                           --rollback to 2 here; 

                            --savepoint 3 here; 
perform   testUpdateAdjust3(
        tname       => 'Test3',
        custnumber  => 'custno1123',
        custid      => 54,
        regid       => 'F'
       );     
                         --rollback to 3 here;

    end $$ language plpgsql;
```

The requirement is

First update    "confi" table.
Then testUpdateAdjust1 execution is completed then Rollback the operations  done by testUpdateAdjust1 only.
After testUpdateAdjust2 execution is completed then Rollback the operations  done by testUpdateAdjust2 only.
After testUpdateAdjust3 execution is completed then Rollback the operations  done by testUpdateAdjust3 only.

After all three functions executed then the UPDATE statement should be rollbacked.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot roll back some of the statements in a transaction and commit the others. It is “all or nothing”.

You can issue a second `UPDATE` statement that undoes the effect of the first one.